# 入れ子になった json から１次元配列を生成する

Tags: javascript, json

```js
const data = {
    list: [
        {
            item: [1 ,2]
        },
        {
            item: [3 ,4]
        },
         {
            item: [5 ,6]
        }
    ]
}
```

このような json データから１次元配列

```
[ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ]
```

を得たいのですが、どのように記述するのがよいでしょうか。
出来るだけループを使用したくないのですが、それは難しいでしょうか。

ちなみに

```
const array = data.list.map(function(a) {return a.item})
```

とした場合は、以下のように入れ子の配列になってしまいました。

```
[ [ 1, 2 ], [ 3, 4 ], [ 5, 6 ] ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

もし `flatMap` が使える環境ならば、`flatMap` を使うとシンプルに記述できます。

```
const array = data.list.flatMap(function(a) {return a.item});
```

`flat` が使えるならば、ネストした配列をフラットにすることもできます。

```
const array = data.list.map(function(a) {return a.item}).flat()
```

また `reduce` と `concat` を使って記述することも可能です。

```
const array = data.list.reduce((acc, x) => acc.concat(x.item), [])
```

- 参考

  - https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap
  - https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat

Answer (score 2):

英語版Stackoverflowに配列をflattanする方法についての回答で`Array.prototype.concat`が使われておりました。

```
const array = data.list.map(function(a) {return a.item})
Array.prototype.concat.apply([], array)
```

でいかがでしょうか？

また、まだECMAScriptの標準にはなっていませんが`flat`という関数を使って

```
array.flat(1);
```

という書き方もできるようです。

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10865042/1536527